# How do I increase the size of int, so that i could store the value of 5 ^ 30 in it

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to write a program and the requirement is to store the power of 5^30 into int but when I'm trying to do it, it gives a output as a negative number.
It runs fine with double or long

```
#include <stdio.h>

int PowerFive(){

    int a, i, n=5, e=1;
    for (i = 0; i<=30; i++)
    {
        a=e;
        printf("%d, ", e);
        e = e*n;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    PowerFive();
}
```

Comment: Why should it fit into a long? `30 * math.log(5) / math.log(2) = 69.66 > 63`.

Comment: There isn't a standard size of integer that'll contain 5³⁰ — `bc` says: `5^30 =
931322574615478515625` and 
`2^63 = 
9223372036854775808` and there are 2 more decimal digits in 5^30 than in 2^63.  Consequently, you'd need more than 64 bits of integer to store 5^30.  You could simulate a 128-bit number with 2 64-bit numbers.

Comment: Are you sure the requirement was for "an `int` value" and not "an integer value"?

Answer (score 1):

> increase the size of int

Compilers sometimes offer controls of `int` size, yet often that is fixed to the target system as 32, 16, 64, .. bits.  It must be at least 16.

> store the value of 5 ^ 30

5<sup>30</sup> is 931322574615478515625, a 70 bit number.

C does not specify an integer type wide enough for that, although some systems do support 128 bit integer.

Lacking 128-bit integers, to store that integer value requires a different approach.  Various arbitrary width libraries exists.

A quickie is to use a *string* - not very efficient, but gets the job done.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strmult(char *s, size_t size, unsigned char m) {
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  if (len >= size) {
    return NULL;
  }
  int carry = 0;
  for (size_t i = len; i-- > 0;) {
    if (!isdigit((unsigned char ) s[i])) {
      return NULL;
    }
    int sum = (s[i] - '0') * m + carry;
    s[i] = sum % 10 + '0';
    carry = sum / 10;
  }
  while (carry) {
    if (len + 1 >= size) {
      return NULL;
    }
    memmove(s + 1, s, len + 1);
    s[0] = carry + '0';
    carry /= 10;
  }
  return s;
}

int main(void) {
  char s[100] = "1";
  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    strmult(s, sizeof s, 5);
  }
  puts(s);
}
```

Output

```
931322574615478515625
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't; `int` has a fixed size.

`long` may be larger than `int`, but it looks like you need more than 64 bits to get the **correct** answer.  In that case, your best bet is probably to use `__int128`.

Comment: Yes, there is, see comment.

Comment: That's right.. We have used long and it works but the requirement is that we have to return an int value

Comment: Ah, I was mislead by OP saying "It runs fine with double or long".  In that case, __int128 it is…

Comment: Or maybe the requirement is that the return value be an integer type, not necessarily an `int`.  `__int128` would qualify as an integer type.

Answer (score 0):

The number of bit/bytes of `int`, `long`, `double`, ... is implementation/platform dependent.

For that reason, on some platforms this may not work with `long`.

The a note about 'it works with `double`': In general, with `double` or `float` you may think it worked, but the answer could be wrong: rounded to a value close to the correct answer.

You have to implement your own big-int code that uses 3 (or more) `int`s.

Comment: Would it be possible to do something with Malloc?

Comment: @AliAshar: Since your code doesn't use `malloc()`, the problem you're encountering is nothing to do with `malloc()`.  The problem is that you're trying to fit 70 bits of data into a 32-bit value, and that simply doesn't work very well.

Comment: @AliAshar: Using simply an `int` won't work, that's correct.  It would be possible to create a structure using 3 or 4 32-bit `int` values to simulate a 96-bit or 128-bit integer, and then do the calculation using that type.  You'd need to consider how to handle the sign bit, too (so you might be using `unsigned int` rather than `signed int`).  But using simple variable of `int` type won't work.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE : quick note on how to get `5^30` very quickly, without needing a dedicated `bigint` package :

> ```
> {m,g}awk 'BEGIN { CONVFMT=OFMT="%.250g"
>     
>  print _ = int(__=(_+=(_^=_<_)+(_+=_))^(__+=__=++_+--_) * \
>               (_+=_^=!_)^-_^++_) int((__-int(__))*(--_+(_*=_+_))^_) }'
> ```

```
931322574615478515625
```

In fact, using the same technique, you can leverage `double-precision` floating point and perform a very specific type of multiplication/squaring MUCH faster than dedicated `bigint` packages :

```
   fgc; 
   ( time ( perl -le 'use bigint; my $__=5; $__**=537;
                       $__*=88777979; print int(($__)*($__))'        
   ) | gfactor ) | sanitize_gnu_factor
   sleep .5
   ( time ( python3 -c '_=537; __=88777979; ___=2;____=5;
                        print(int(pow(pow(____,_)*__,___)))' 
   ) | gfactor ) | sanitize_gnu_factor
   sleep .5
   ( time ( gawk -Mbe 'BEGIN { _=537; __=88777979; ___=2
                               ____=5; print (____^_*__)^___ }'  
   ) | gfactor ) | sanitize_gnu_factor
   sleep .5
   ( time ( mawk2 'BEGIN { CONVFMT=OFMT= "%."(-(_+=++_)-(_+=_)+_^_)"g"

        print substr("",
             (_=sprintf("%.*g",_^_++*_--,
             (__=88777979)*__*_^-_^_-- * \
             (--_)^(_++^_^--_-_*(___=(_^++_)^_+_^_+_^!_-_++)))\
              \
               )~(___="^[+-]?[0]+[.][0]+"(__="")) ? sub(___,__,_) \
               : gsub("[.]|^[+-]*[0]*|[Ee][+-]?[0-9]+$",__,_))_ }'

   ) | gfactor ) | sanitize_gnu_factor

389399298996824262817161994......640522278845310211181640625 } 767 dgts :
    5^1,074
    88,777,979^2
    
( perl -le ; )  0.03s user 0.00s system 95% cpu 0.034 total
gfactor  0.00s user 0.00s system 10% cpu 0.034 total
389399298996824262817161994......640522278845310211181640625 } 767 dgts :
    5^1,074
    88,777,979^2
    
( python3 -c ; )  0.02s user 0.01s system 86% cpu 0.035 total
gfactor  0.00s user 0.00s system 15% cpu 0.034 total
389399298996824262817161994......640522278845310211181640625 } 767 dgts :
    5^1,074
    88,777,979^2
    
( gawk -Mbe ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 64% cpu 0.011 total
gfactor  0.00s user 0.00s system 39% cpu 0.011 total

( mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 59% cpu 0.005 total
gfactor  0.00s user 0.00s system 77% cpu 0.006 total

389399298996824262817161994......640522278845310211181640625 } 767 dgts :
    5^1,074
    88,777,979^2
```

- the task : full precision squaring of **`( 5 ** 537 ) * 88777979`**, a result that's `767 decimal digits` long and approx. **`2546.55817-bits`**.

using only user-level scripting, `IEEE 754` double precision floating point math, plus a tiny bit of cleanup string ops, **`mawk2`**, an app that no built-in `bigint` support at all, came out faster than all of these :

1. `perl 5.34`      with bigint package enabled,
2. `python 3.10.6`  with built-in big-int support, and
3. `gnu-gawk 5.1.1` with `gnu-GMP` bigint package

======================================================

you get `integer powers of 5` in the inclusive range of `[-1023, 1074]` essentially for free whenever your platform uses `IEEE 754` double precision floating point math, so you don't really have to "store" them per se :

> ```
> jot - -100 100 13 | 
> mawk '($++NF = +(__=$!____)<-(___=(_^=_<_)-+-++_+_)*!_\
>                    ? sprintf("%.fe%.f", _^-__,+__)     \
>                :+__<(___^_-_)                           \
>                    ? ___^__ : substr(___="", _=sprintf("%.*f",__,
>                        _^-__), sub("^[0.]+",___,_))_)_' CONVFMT='%.20g'
> ```

```
-100 1267650600228229401496703205376e-100
-87 154742504910672534362390528e-87
-74 18889465931478580854784e-74
-61 2305843009213693952e-61
-48 281474976710656e-48
-35 34359738368e-35
-22 4194304e-22
-9 512e-9
4 625
17 762939453125
```

> *`30 931322574615478515625`*

```
43 1136868377216160297393798828125
56 1387778780781445675529539585113525390625
69 1694065894508600678136645001359283924102783203125
82 2067951531382569187178521730174907133914530277252197265625
95 2524354896707237777317531408904915934954260592348873615264892578125
```